# Building and Using pydrake from source

Tags: drake

I am simply trying to build and use pydrake from source. I have seen the Jupyter notebooks on how to use pydrake and they are helpful, but I would like to do this from source on my machine. I am unable to find instructions anywhere on how to build pydrake and use it from source. I have tried `bazel build bindings/pydrake` and then run

```py
>>> import pydrake
```

from within the drake/bindings directory, but I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake.common._module_py'`. What is the usual workflow for building and then using the python bindings?

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to build from source? Is there something that's not in the nightly binaries? https://drake.mit.edu/from_binary.html

Comment: I am trying to write python bindings for my own C++ code that uses drake. I am using pydrake as an example and wanted to understand how pydrake is written, built, and used before attempting to write my own bindings.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do the `drake_bazel_external` workflow; specifically, here's an example of using Drake, writing your own C++ code, and writing Python bindings for them: [simple_adder_py.cc](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/blob/6c8b7629c7c71ea8dc74b62ef59d283ca83c1a50/drake_bazel_external/apps/simple_adder_py.cc#L55-L68), [simple_adder_py_test.py](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/blob/6c8b7629c7c71ea8dc74b62ef59d283ca83c1a50/drake_bazel_external/apps/simple_adder_py_test.py#L57-L82). Can you check out if this does what you need?

Comment: If you are writing code in CMake, here's a parallel example: [drake_cmake_installed/src/simple_bindings](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/6c8b7629c7c71ea8dc74b62ef59d283ca83c1a50/drake_cmake_installed/src/simple_bindings)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Is the only way to run the python bindings by creating a `py_test()` or a `py_binary()` in the BUILD.bazel file? Or rather, is there a way I can just write a python script that imports the bindings and run it directly on the command line, eg. `python apps/simple_adder_py_test.py`?

Comment: If you're writing C++ and binding that in Python, I'd highly recommend to sticking with the `BUILD.bazel` file and `bazel run` as the way to execute your script. That work for you for the time being?

(otherwise, you may have to spend wayyy more time than is useful hacking paths and stuff)

Comment: That's fine. I am new to bazel so I thought that would make things easier. I am now learning the bazel way of doing things. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could follow the instruction on https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#building-the-python-bindings

Namely instead of build drake with bazel, you will need to do

```
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake ../drake
make -j
```

and then set your PYTHONPATH accordingly.

Comment: See also - examples of using Drake in external projects: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/

Comment: So there is no way to install the bindings with bazel?

Comment: There is, but we don't really support it as public interface, so YMMV. You can do `bazel run //:install -- --help` to build everything, then see how you can install it.